# Android Studio import already compiled C++ Library

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface

I made a C++ library compiled with Visual studio because I had to done it and now I must use it for an android project.

I'm not very good at using Android studio. If it was plain Java I would have been fine but I have to import my library into the project and use JNI to make the link with the actual Java code.

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2 and gradle plugin 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting you correctly you want to include the library in your project. If it is so you need to add your library in libs folder of your project, then copy the library file in libs folder.

Right Click on it and select "Add as Library".